# Detecting vertical (y axis) rotation on iphone 3gs

Tags: iphone, ipad, rotation

The iphone 4 and above does have an gyroscope so there I would detect any rotation with this sensor. But on the iPhone 3GS there is only an accelarometer that can not detect any rotation at least if you rotate it around the z axis, ie lying flat on a table and rotating it in a flat manner ;).

Now, would it be possible to detect a rotation in some way if I would flip the iphone 3gs I mean rotating around the y-axis or x-axis and not flat on the table. Or would that be impossible as well?

Answer (score 0):

In short: it is impossible in general, it might be possible under certain conditions.

Accelerometers always measure gravity. If you are rotating around an axis different from the z-axis then you will see changes in the acceleration readings due to gravity. For example, if you put the phone on a slightly tilted turntable you will get a sine wave in the x and y acceleration readings.

Here is the fundamental problem. You have to know that the phone is only rotated but is not accelerated. Otherwise the change you see in the acceleration readings might as well come from the acceleration of the phone.